# Placing Fans in frames

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FigurePanel extends JPanel {
  // Define constants
  public static final int LINE = 1;
  public static final int RECTANGLE = 2;
  public static final int ROUND_RECTANGLE = 3;
  public static final int OVAL = 4;
  public static final int ARC = 5;
  public static final int POLYGON = 6;

  private int type = 1;
  private boolean filled;

  /** Construct a default FigurePanel */
  public FigurePanel() {
  }

  /** Construct a FigurePanel with the specified type */
  public FigurePanel(int type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  /** Construct a FigurePanel with the specified type and filled */
  public FigurePanel(int type, boolean filled) {
    this.type = type;
    this.filled = filled;
  }

  /** Draw a figure on the panel */
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Get the appropriate size for the figure
    int width = getSize().width;
    int height = getSize().height;

    switch (type) {
      case LINE: // Display two cross lines
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10);
        g.drawLine(width - 10, 10, 10, height - 10);
        break;
      case RECTANGLE: // Display a rectangle
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        if (filled)
          g.fillRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.1 * height),
            (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.8 * height));
        else
          g.drawRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.1 * height),
            (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.8 * height));
        break;
      case ROUND_RECTANGLE: // Display a round-cornered rectangle
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        if (filled)
          g.fillRoundRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.1 * height),
            (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.8 * height), 20, 20);
        else
          g.drawRoundRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.1 * height),
            (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.8 * height), 20, 20);
        break;
      case OVAL: // Display an oval
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (filled)
          g.fillOval((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.1 * height),
            (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.8 * height));
        else
          g.drawOval((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.1 * height),
            (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.8 * height));
        break;
      case ARC: // Display an arc
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (filled) {
          int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
          int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
          int radius =
            (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

          int x = xCenter - radius;
          int y = yCenter - radius;

          g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
          g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
          g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
          g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
        }
        else {
          int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
          int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
          int radius =
            (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

          int x = xCenter - radius;
          int y = yCenter - radius;

          g.drawArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
          g.drawArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
          g.drawArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
          g.drawArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
        };
        break;
      case POLYGON: // Display a polygon
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
        int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
        int radius =
          (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

        // Create a Polygon object
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();

        // Add points to the polygon
        polygon.addPoint(xCenter + radius, yCenter);
        polygon.addPoint((int)(xCenter + radius *
          Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / 6)), (int)(yCenter - radius *
          Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / 6)));
        polygon.addPoint((int)(xCenter + radius *
          Math.cos(2 * 2 * Math.PI / 6)), (int)(yCenter - radius *
          Math.sin(2 * 2 * Math.PI / 6)));
        polygon.addPoint((int)(xCenter + radius *
          Math.cos(3 * 2 * Math.PI / 6)), (int)(yCenter - radius *
          Math.sin(3 * 2 * Math.PI / 6)));
        polygon.addPoint((int)(xCenter + radius *
          Math.cos(4 * 2 * Math.PI / 6)), (int)(yCenter - radius *
          Math.sin(4 * 2 * Math.PI / 6)));
        polygon.addPoint((int)(xCenter + radius *
          Math.cos(5 * 2 * Math.PI / 6)), (int)(yCenter - radius *
          Math.sin(5 * 2 * Math.PI / 6)));

        // Draw the polygon
        if (filled)
          g.fillPolygon(polygon);
        else
          g.drawPolygon(polygon);
    }
  }

  /** Set a new figure type */
  public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
   // repaint();
  }

  /** Return figure type */
  public int getType() {
    return type;
  }

  /** Set a new filled property */
  public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
    this.filled = filled;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Check if the figure is filled */
  public boolean isFilled() {
    return filled;
  }

  /** Specify preferred size */
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(80, 80);
  }
}
```

^ That is Figure Panel class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class fan extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new fan();
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setTitle("Exercise13_09");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public fan() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.ARC, true));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.OVAL));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.ARC, true));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.OVAL, true));
  }
}
```

This is the fan class

I'm currently trying to make a picture of a fan to show up on the screen and was wondering if there was a way to make it draw both the arc and oval in the same spot? I have been messing around with the Figure panel class but I'm not quite sure how I could merge ARC true with OVAL. Help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `drawOval()` at the end of the `fill` branch of `case ARC`:

```
g.drawOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
```

Also consider `RenderingHints`:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Comment: Thank you, now another question, If I run the Figure panel class I get the fan I want with that added change, is there anyway to make it do that when I call it with the fan class?

Comment: @user1864655 Probably not the way your doing it at the moment.  I'd create an intermediate container add the code from the main frame to it, then add that container to the frame.

Comment: @MadProgrammer is right; note how `OVAL` and `ARC` grow differently as the container is resized.